# AttributeError: function 'usb_detach_kernel_driver_np' not found

Tags: python, usb, ctypes, libusb, pyusb

I've been trying to print a simple receipt with an Epson TM-t20ii using Python 2.7 and [python-escpos](http://python-escpos.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). installed the printer drivers, also  copied the libusb 1.2.6 .sys and .dll files to their respective folder.

Heres how the program looks like:

```
from escpos import *

Generic = printer.Usb(0x04B8,0x0E15)
Generic.text("Test Print!\n")
Generic.cut()
```

And this is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Proyectos/QT/PymePOS/pymepos/pyscrpts/print.py", line 7, in <module>
    Generic = printer.Usb(0x04B8,0x0E15)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\escpos\printer.py", line 34, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\escpos\printer.py", line 52, in open
    self.device.detach_kernel_driver(0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 1005, in detach_kernel_driver
    interface)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb0.py", line 541, in detach_kernel_driver
    _check(_lib.usb_detach_kernel_driver_np(dev_handle, intf))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 378, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 383, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: function 'usb_detach_kernel_driver_np' not found
```

Im using Win10 64bits and printitng thorught usb
Any workarrounds or solutions!?
Thanks!

Comment: `usb_detach_kernel_driver_np` is only available in libusb on Linux. According to the [TODO list](http://python-escpos.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/todo.html), python-escpos hasn't been ported to Windows.

Comment: i saw some bypassed that call so i tried to do it aswell... however now i get a different error.
`usb.core.USBError: [Errno None] libusb0-dll:err [control_msg] sending control message failed, win error: The system cannot find the file specified.` @eryksun any idea?